# Installing CUDA 5.0

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I want to install the CUDA 5.0 toolkit package from the Ubuntu public repository but it needs to remove my Nvidia 319.27 driver which I do not want to be removed- It needs to remove it as it has been packaged with the older 304 driver.

How can I install the CUDA 5.0 toolkit without having to remove my Nvidia 319.27 driver?

Comment: I don't want to affront you - thinking only that CUDA 5.0 toolkit is software made
by nvidia.com - and there is a forum special for developers with this toolkit at nvidia.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply download the CUDA 5 package from nVidia and install it - but do not install driver when asked. I have it installed on my three computers and it works just fine on each. To see if everything works run NSight and run the template CUDA project. If necessary (I doubt it) reinstall your driver.